# How to determine if Google Analytics is accurate

Tags: web, google-analytics

I've got a website and I'm tracking its traffic with Google Analytics. Besides, on some pages, I have a counter which is simply incremented each time the page is requested.

I noticed that most of the time, Google Analytics and my counters disagree (GA roughly indactes only half the number of my counter). So I fetched my web servers logs, and for one specific page I calculated the number of different IP addresses who accessed it. At the end, I have :

- Google Analytics : 966 views
- Counter : 2716 views
- Unique IP addresses : 2462 IPs

So my counter and the weblogs seem to confirm each other. I'm a bit surprised that GA seems wrong (you would suspect Google to be able to give correct analytics ...). Any clues of what is happening here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have bot filtering turned on? Some people have "Do not track" turned on in their browser, or extensions which explicitly block Google Analytics. Google Analytics is as accurate as the data that is sent to it.

Comment: Other than bot filtering, if you have custom filters (like internal IP etc) applied on original view, it would also reduce views count. I assume you mean Pageviews, not Unique Pageviews.